# Invalid Number is returned by Regexp_replace

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace

I want to remove titles like Dr., Mr. Jr. from name. `Regexp_replace` should Search and remove Dr. Mr. Jr and search should be case insensitive, final output should not have `.` or `,` or extra spaces in name.

```
select regexp_replace('DR. Mr. Mr Dr Radha Jr Jr. Krishnan Jr.','(Dr|Mr|Jr)(\W|\w|$|,)',1,0,'i') 
from dual
```

I am getting invalid number error.

Comment: What is your actual expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution lacks in two aspects.

The more important is that you may cut of the leading "titles" from names:

```
select regexp_replace('DR. Mr. Mr Dr Dradha Jr Jr. Mrishnan Jr.','(Dr|Mr|Jr)(\W|\w|$|,)','',1,0,'i') 
from dual
```

which returns a not expected result

```
dha  shnan
```

The remedy is to allow only the *non word characters* (`\W`) and end of line (`$`) *after the title*.

If you enforce optional space or begin of the line (`^`) *before  the title*, you get rid of the second problem the spaces left after the remove of titles

```
select regexp_replace('DR. Mr. Mr Dr Dradha Jr Jr. Mr, Mrishnan Jr.',
  '( *|^)(Dr|Mr|Jr)(\W|$)','',1,0,'i') 
from dual

Dradha Mrishnan
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgott what to replace with between pattern and 1

```
select regexp_replace('DR. Mr. Mr Dr Radha Jr Jr. Krishnan Jr.','(Dr|Mr|Jr)(\W|\w|$|,)','',1,0,'i') 
from dual
```

Comment: Oh!.. Thanks but i am getting extra spaces in output.    select length(regexp_replace('DR. Mr. Mr Dr Radha Jr Jr. Krishnan Jr.','(Dr|Mr|Jr)(\W|\w|$|,)','',1,0,'i')) from dual

Comment: @MKS That wasn't part of the question

Answer (score 0):

The following query will remove multiple empty spaces and trim the leading space too:

```
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE('DR. Mr. Mr Dr Radha Jr Jr. Krishnan Jr.', '(Dr|Mr|Jr)(\W|\w|$|,)', '', 1, 0, 'i')
       , ' {2,}', ' ')) AS "Result"
FROM Dual
```

It will return the result as `Radha Krishnan`

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0b2dd80f0e37bf7b952fb63b4568f457)

Comment: @MKS You can't accept multiple answers. Among the answers which one is fulfilled your expected result, you may select only one accepted answer for your question.